# How to add django template variable in <img src>?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a Photo model with two fields:

```
title = models.CharField()
path = models.CharField()
```

When I adding the new photo in admin panel, the path is equals to `/images/image_ex.jpg` This is my view file:

```
def gallery(request):
   photos = Photo.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'gallery.html', {'photos': photos})
```

This is the  tag in gallery.html:

```
{% loadstaticfiles %}
<img src="{%static '{{photo.path}}'%}"/>
```

The problem is that the photo does not render and if I look in the code of the page, the src is equals to something like that:

```
src="static/%7B%7B%20photo.path%20%7D%7D"
```

What is the problem? How can I use template variables in src?
P.S. The images folder exists in static folder,  the image exists too. I added static directory to settings.py. Also if I change src to a normal one, like

```
<img src="{static 'images/image_ex.png'%}">
```

The photo renders normally.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a `FileField`?

Comment: As for the url, it should be `<img src="{%static photo.path %}"/>` But I'm not convinced that this will work, since you did not specify a `photo` variable.

Comment: The photo variable is specified higher in code: i've got a cycle {%for photo in photos %}. And {%static photo.path %} does not work

Comment: well `{% static photo.path %}` will give a static URL, but it might still be better to use a `FileField` here.

Comment: Well, I used it, but when I choose the photo, the path is just the image name. How can I make the path to be images/image_name.png

Comment: given that holds, why do you use `{% static .. %}` in the first place? The idea of `{% static ... %}` is that you have *dedicated* directories (named `static`), and you allow to access these and the view returns the correct file stream. But you can not just return a random file from the server, since that would be one of the most critical security problems possible. You thus need some "views" in place to limit access. That is exactly one of the ideas behind a file field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/files/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You here pass `'{{photo.path}}'` as a *string* to `{% static ... %}`, hence it will simply prepend the static URL root to this string.

If you want to use the *content* of `photo.path`, you can use:

```
<img src="{% static photo.path %}"/>
```

So `{% static ... %}` accepts variables as parameters, and will take the content of the `path` attribute of the `photo` variable. (of course given that variable is passed, or is a variable you generate with `{% for ... %}` loops, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```html
<img src="{%static 'images/'%}{{image_ex.png}}">
```

Use it after the static tag scope ends.

Answer (score 1):

**Uses a for tag**

```
{% for p in photos %}
    <img src="{% static '{{ p.path }}' %}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

**Better uses Imagefield as field in your model**

**In your settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Create a folder named “media” in your project (at the same level that your apps)

**In your urls.py (main)**

```
from . import views, settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**In your models.py**

Replace the CharField with Imagefield

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="my_folder_name")
```

**Like this:**

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="my_folder_name"))
```

**In your views.py**

```
def gallery(request):
   photos = Photo.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'gallery.html', {'photos': photos})
```

**In your templates**

```
{% for p in photos %}
    <img src="{{ p.photo.url }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Template**

```
{% for image in all_image %}
    <img src="{{ image.image.url }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved: load image dynamically in survey.html**

> "survey.toolsTechnology" is a dynamic variable, every time the
> variable changes, the image also changes based on it.

```
<img src="{% static 'images/'%}{{survey.toolsTechnology}}.png"/>
```