# ValueError at / The 'photo' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: python, html, django, pycharm

**THE PROBLEM :**

I want to upload the images of my product file onto the server. But when I am passing the file URL which is
`<{{product.photo.url}}>` in my HTML file it is displaying **value error: photo attribute has no files associated with it.**

My python and HTML file code below:

**product.py file**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import ImageField

from .category import Category
class Product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/product/',
                          blank=True)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=300,
                                blank=True)
price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

@staticmethod
def get_all_products():
    return Product.objects.all()
```

In the above code for `Imagefield`, I have passed the 'photo' variable but then too the server is displaying error.

**urls.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import settings
urlpatterns = [
              path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
              path('', include('store.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**`Index.html` code**:

```
 <body>

      
<div.<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    {% for product in products %}
  <div class="card mx-auto mb-3 mt-3" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="{{product.photo.url}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-title"><b>{{product.name}}</b></p>
      <p class="card-text"><b>{{product.price}}</b>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-light border btn-md">Add To Cart</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

**The confusing thing is when I am passing the code `{{product.image.url}}` instead of `{{product.photo.url}}` it is displaying overall output BUT NOT the product image**

**`settings.py` code:**

```
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'

   MEDIA_URL = '/test/'

   MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR
```

**I think it is not reading/fetching the URL from source; how should I resolve this?**

Comment: yes sir thankyou so much. I have seen your answer and its pretty informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your files and code are a bit confusing but this is what I think.**

The error

> ValueError at / The 'photo'

is pretty clear. The `photo` has no file/attribute associated with it. I am also unsure as to what you expect this `{{product.photo.url}` to output — as from what I can see this will yield no value. If you think `product` refers to the file and `photo` refers to the defined attribute and `url` is an indirect variable of the `photo` object then this is a wrong approach.

See this answer here on how you should go about embedding URL in the `src` tag - [How to add django template variable in img src tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52803129/how-to-add-django-template-variable-in-img-src)