# Django: How to add context variable as src to url?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have a django model with a field for an external URL

```
image_url = models.URLField(max_length=250)
```

I want to then display an image associated with that image_url (say https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Pocky-Sticks.jpg) in an html img element like so

```
<img src=image_url alt="didn't find image">
```

where i have passed image_url in as a context variable. When I try the naive method of just passing in a context variable

```
<img src= "{{ model.image_url }}" alt="didn't find image">
```

I can never find the image. I have looked around and most answers for similar questions are related to loading an image from static (e.g. [How to add django template variable in <img src>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52803129/how-to-add-django-template-variable-in-img-src). ) These haven't been helpful because I want to load an image from a path completely external to my app.

Any ideas on how to pass in a context variable to src in this case?

Comment: <img src= "/media/{{ model.image_url }}" alt="didn't find image">  If you have /media/ as MEDIA_URL in settings

Comment: But I want the url to remain external to my app. Why should I have to edit my settings to allow me to link to an external URL?